# publicly accessible rds and public/private subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

In AWS, if I have an RDS in a subnet that has had it's public accessibility feature turned off, do I need to worry about making its subnet private? If so, how would I go about making the subnet private? (assuming it was public beforehand)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Publicly Accessible** flag on an Amazon RDS database determines whether its DNS Name can be resolved outside of the VPC.

By setting `Publicly Accessible = No`, the database is unreachable from the Internet. However, if you wish to keep the database private, it is also advisable to modify the **Security Group** associated with the Amazon RDS instance to only permit access from the VPC or, preferably, only from the resources that need to access the database.

A further level of security can be obtained by putting the Amazon RDS database in a **private subnet**. This is an additional layer of security. It is not *necessary* to keep your database private (the above two methods are already doing that), but networking and security professionals like to keep most resources in a private subnet, and the only resources they put in a public subnet will be those that need to be accessible from the Internet (eg a Load Balancer or maybe a web server).

So, the choice is yours... you do not *need* to move it to a private subnet. It depends on your corporate security policies. But, at a minimum, do make sure it is locked-down via the Security Group.

Comment: in my RDS instance, I currently have 4 security groups listed - should I only have 1?

Comment: You can have multiple security groups. Access will be granted if the traffic matches any rules in _any_ of the associated security groups.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The access is provided only if the accessor matches the IP of the VPC. To check your statement I have tried connecting with a VPN connection. The DNS was getting resolved but I was not able to connect (and telnet). [Publicly Accessible = No , VPN Connected, Security Group has all the ports allowed on VPN CIDR and VPC CIDR]